# Call methods on fields of specific class

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I need a simple way to call a specific method of all fields of a certain type within a class. (Applies to C#/Unity3D)

Example:

```
public class Item{
    public void Update(){
    }
    //....
}

public class Container{
    Item a = new Item();
    Item b = new Item();
    Item c = new Item();//etc

    public void UpdateAllItems();//<-- calls Update for a, b, c
}
```

Restrictions:

1. `Item`s should not explicitly store any reference to `Container`. It should not require `Container` as a constructor parameter.
2. `Item`s should be normal fields/variables. (meaning that replacing them with an array or even a hash is not a good idea. Making a property for each item also isn't a good idea.)
3. If I decide to add more `Item`s or remove some of them, I should not need to modify my code anywhere. So, `a.Update(); b.Update();` is not a solution. `magicInternalContainer.Add(a); ... foreach(var item in magicInternalContaier)` also is not suitable.
4. `Item`s should not derive from `MonoBehavior` or `Component`. It is a lightweight object.

Additional info:

1. The type of `Item` is known and will not change; they do not have any virtual methods.
2. Expected complexity at runtime: 10–200 `Container` objects, with 10–20 `Item`s each, 30–60 calls to `UpdateAllItems` per second, most likely in a single thread.
3. Item is very lightweight. The contents of the class are a few floats — it easily could've been a struct.
4. `Item`s are not going to be dynamically added or removed at runtime.

Advice? It looks like `Type.GetFields` is the way to go, but it seems that this uses reflection and people keep warning that "Reflection is slow!" pretty much everywhere. Alternatively I would need to replace the variables with `HashSet`, add a couple of wrappers and address the items using some `Enum` ids (and I'll need to babysit unity serialization in this case, because unity does not serialize generics without additional help).

What's the proper way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, since you wrote

> `Items` are not going to be dynamically added or removed at runtime.

I would suggest creating another field that will be collection of items, and populate it in the constructor of the container class using reflection.
Then, in the `UpdateAllItems()` method you can iterate this collection and do whatever you want.

This way you don't have to change anything in your code when adding or removing items, you don't need to worry about reflection performance since the reflection process only runs once for every container, and you have no restrictions whatsoever on the type of Item, accept the one restriction that you can't avoid anyway, which is that it has an `Update()` method.

Comment: No. I explicitly mentioned that I don't want this kind of solution in "restriction #3". The class is being prototyped, so I add/remove those `Item`s often, and I tend to forget to add them to manual update procedure. If I add collection variable, then I"ll be forgetting to add them to that collection instead. Same thing, in different place. I want to declare every item exactly ONCE, in exactly one place, without extra step elsewhere.

Comment: You didn't understand my suggestion. the population of the Items collection should be in runtime, using reflection. There is no need for you to specify the Items in more then one place. The point was to do all the reflection stuff in the constructor, to minimize it's impact on performance.